# How to load values via System.Text.Json from a file and store them readonly?

Tags: c#, json, readonly, system.text.json

I want to load settings from a JSON-file via System.Text.Json.
These settings should all be readonly after being loaded.

My code so far:

```
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filename);
Settings s = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Settings>(jsonString);
```

And the Settings-class:

```
public class Settings
{
    public decimal A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public double C { get; set; }
    public double D { get; set; }
}
```

The problem: The values are editable and using `private set;` does not work because JsonSerializer needs to be able to access the setters.

Comment: `JsonSerializer` does not support immutable classes and structs, see [JsonSerializer support for immutable classes and structs. #38569](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38569).  You'll need to use a custom converter or DTO.  Is your question *can can this be done straightforwardly*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base class with public `set` for the serializer and then override them in derived class which does does not allow them to be mutated.

---

I suggest that you change design and make a base class with all the properties mutable and that will be the target of any deserialization operation (*since mutable properties play well with deserialization*). Then a consumer will get the immutable instance via covert/copy/reflect it from that base class.

```
var bse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MutablePropertyStore>("{ 'PropertyB' : true }");
Console.WriteLine("Base:    " +  bse.ToString());   

var derived = new ImmutablePropertyStore(bse);              
Console.WriteLine("Derived: " + derived.ToString());
```

**Result**

```
Base:    Property A is 'False' and Property B is 'True'.
Derived: Property A is 'False' and Property B is 'True'.
```

---

Example [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ebgdPq)

**Code**

```
public sealed class ImmutablePropertyStore : MutablePropertyStore
{
    public new bool PropertyA { get; private set; }
    public new bool PropertyB { get; private set; }

    public ImmutablePropertyStore() { }

    public ImmutablePropertyStore(MutablePropertyStore ms)
    {
        PropertyA = ms.PropertyA;
        PropertyB = ms.PropertyB;
    }

    public ImmutablePropertyStore(bool propertyA = true, bool propertyB = false)
    {
        PropertyA = propertyA;
        PropertyB = propertyB;
    }

    public override string ToString() 
        => $"Property A is '{PropertyA}' and Property B is '{PropertyB}'."; 
}

public class MutablePropertyStore
{
    public virtual bool PropertyA { get; set;}
    public virtual bool PropertyB { get; set;}

    // Set all defaults here
    public MutablePropertyStore() {  }

    public override string ToString() 
        => $"Property A is '{PropertyA}' and Property B is '{PropertyB}'.";      

}
```